# Combination/Permutation Type

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose that a class of $130$ students consists of $60$
math majors, and $70$ english majors. The instructor wants to give
cookies to five of the students, and he is going to give them out at random. How many ways can this be done if all of the cookies are different?

Comment: Are math majors different from each other or are then considered as a single collective likewise for the English majors)

Comment: A single collective

Comment: can a student get more than one cookie?

Comment: no they cantttt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cookie can be given to either one of the math's majors or one of the English majors. So there are 5 decisions with two options so $2^5 = 32$ if the students are considered a collective.

Comment: Only if students can get more than one cookie, which would be pretty unfair.